# How to remove Solidify Mod intersections?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

Consider a concave surface being solified in positive normal direction using the Solidify modifier. By nature of this modifier, self-intersections occur on the inside of concave curvatures (see GIF). Using various options of the modifier (Even Thickness, Only Rim, High Quality Normals) do not seem to improve the results.

[image: Artefacts solidify modifier]

Is there a good way to remove these intersections/artefacts and retain only the "outer" surface (see image)?

A solution may involve post-processing after applying this modifier and does not even have to involve the solidify modifier at all. A Python-coded solution is fine as well.

[image: Outer surface]

Comment: This has been a commonly encountered problem I think, but if there is a solution I’m not aware of it yet. I’m watching…

Comment: Would  _Weld_  and _Remesh_ wreck your model?

Comment: Robin, I tried both modifiers before, but could not determine a solid workflow; what workflow do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out a solid solution. It is demonstrated in the GIF below. Here are the steps:

1. Duplicate the object of interest
2. Create a box of the region of interest
3. Duplicate the box and scale it down just a little bit
4. Use a Boolean mod on the original object with the larger box (exact, intersect)
5. Use a Solidify mod on the duplicate object of interest
6. Use a Remesh mod on the duplicate object
7. Use a Boolean mod on the duplicate object with the smaller box (exact, intersect)
8. Use a Boolean mod on the duplicate object with the original object (exact, difference)

This leaves a nice, solidified object without self-intersections and with the original surface on the back.

Edit: Although this method produces a solid object, the outer surface can be easily extracted by removing the inner surface in Edit Mode.

[image: solidify fix]